# JavaScript: How to keep the original input date format when using new Date()?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date which is in following format "2023-05-19T18:30:00.000Z"
My code is as follows:

```
date(value) {
const myDate = new Date("2023-05-19T18:30:00.000Z")
}
```

Above code is giving date as

```
 "Sat May 20 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Indian Standard Time)".
```

Problem is my input date is 19 May but after doing
new Date it is giving May 20. how can I stop date and time getting changed?

Comment: `new Date(2023, 4, 19, 18, 30, 0, 0)`   Note: Only the date time string format is explicitly specified to be supported. Other formats are implementation-defined and may not work across all browsers.

Comment: You can't. A `Date` object simply represents a timestamp, it does not have a "format". So nothing actually "changes". If you want to get back the string, you can however use `myData.toISOString()` instead of `myData.toString()`  (which uses your system timezone, and results in the output you've shown)

Comment: @Bergi   I think it's more the time, not the format.  I know he says format, but then later says problem is 19 May, is giving 20 May..  IOW: He's using the date constructor with a string, that's getting interpreted as UTC, and then of course locale time is then wrong.

Comment: The two strings you show represent the same moment in time, expressed in different time zones. The "z" on the end of your input string specifies UTC; the output is the same moment specified in the local time zone of India, which at that moment was 5 hours 30 minutes ahead of UTC. So, is what you're asking "how to format a date object as UTC rather than local time?"

Comment: Do you need the time? If you only need the date, do `const myDate = new Date("2023-05-19T18:30:00:000z").toISOString().split("T")[0]`

Comment: Can we please find a canonical *'it's just a different timezone'* dupe?

Comment: @keith—there are [three supported formats](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-date.parse): those produced by *toString*, *toISOString* and *toUTCString*.

Comment: Hi @RobG , not sure why you pinged me that one. :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(new Date("2023-05-19T18:30:00.000Z").toString())
```

Here you are using [Date time string format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_time_string_format) to initialize `Date` object, where trailing `Z` means you're setting it with zero [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), so that it represents [UTC+00:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B00:00) timezone. *(Thanks to @RobG for clarification.)*

However, when you're converting your `Date` object back into a string, it defaults to a local time zone of the user and translates date and time accordingly, which is why you're seeing them different (unless your local time zone is exactly UTC+00:00).

To obtain a string in explicit correspondence with UTC+00:00, use [toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) method:

```js
console.log(new Date("2023-05-19T18:30:00.000Z").toUTCString())
```

Also you can get any of the `Date` components as a number:

```js
let date = new Date("2023-05-19T18:30:00.000Z");
console.log(
    `Year: ${date.getUTCFullYear()},`,
    `Month: ${date.getUTCMonth() + 1},`, // note: month is zero-based, so has to be incremented!
    `Day: ${date.getUTCDate()},`,
    `Hours: ${date.getUTCHours()},`,
    `Minutes: ${date.getUTCMinutes()},`,
    `Seconds: ${date.getUTCSeconds()},`,
    `Milliseconds: ${date.getUTCMilliseconds()}`
);
```

Comment: "*…you're setting it as UTC*" is incorrect. The trailing Z means **parse** it as UTC, the internal representation is a [time value](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) (millisecond offset from 1 Jan 1970 UTC), it has no format or timezone. PS UTC is a time standard, not a timezone. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Thanks for clarification, I've edited my answer... The next time I feel the urge to post something I lack 5 PhDs in the theoretical background, I will probably just leave it for the others! =) (just being ironic)

Comment: Your answer is fundamentally correct, just allow pedants their pedantry. :-)